# iterate over a list and arrange data

Tags: java, json, list, hashmap

I am getting a list of data in the form of List object from database which contains data as

```
field_id  value dt_updated
1          3    jun-6
2          5    jun-5
1          2    jun-3
3          5    jun-3
```

i want iterate over this list and group data for for fields as per there old and new values.For example:i want create a json like:

```
 "field_1":
       [
           oldvalue"2"
           new value:"3"

       ],
  field_2 :
  [ oldvalue:"5"],
```

i want to iterate over the list and get the old and new values for that field and put in some object.How to perform this? In some cases field will have only old values.

Comment: What have you got so far? (Actually, your example seems to be wrong, as the newest value of field id=1 is 3.)

Comment: I am not getting how will i iterate over the list and for a given field group the old and new values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if entries from database are ordered by dt_update but I assume it's not guaranteed.

Just put your entries from db to `Map(id->DBUpdate)` where `DBUpdate` is some simple value object with `value` and `updateDate` fields into some MultiMap (Available e.g. in Google Guava library). After iterating over all objects from DB sort elementes for each id by `updateDate` (simply by implementing `Comparable` interface in `DBUpdate`) and construct appropriate String (if there is only one value for given id in MultiMap there will be only oldValue, otherwise use first element for new value and second element in MultiMap as oldValue)